# Microsoft Mail Merge Address Block line breaks error

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, mail-merge

I'm currently using mail merge to automate a process for sending letters to brokerage custodians and am merging the address block from an excel sheet. Within the sheet the addresses are pulled from a table using XLOOKUP, and from there data is merged into the document. When the address merge occurs the address block formatting gets messed up, specifically the line breaks. I have gone through and changed added line breaks using "alt+enter" but the block remains wrong. See screenshot below:
*EDIT - For clarification my issue is with importing an address from a single cell in Excel to mail merge in Word. The address formatting is correct in Excel and wrong in Word.
[image: what returns when I select "Preview results"]

Comment: A better description of what you're doing and how will help.

Comment: The AddressBlock has caused problems since its inception. You are better off using individual fields IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You can try entering the carriage return and or new line characters manually into excel:

```
="text"&CHAR(13)&CHAR(10)&"bla blha"
```